A problem on dirt displacement
Definition. Given a function $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ such that $xf\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$, the quantity $\int_\mathbb{R}xf(x)\,dx$ is called the unnormalized center of mass of $f$ and is denoted $UCM(f)$.
Take a 1D flat land at sea level. The profile of my land can be seen as the zero function. My land's UCM is located at $0=\int_\mathbb{R}x\cdot 0\,dx$.
I borrow some amount of dirt from one side of the land (say, left of $w\in \mathbb{R}$) and dump it on the other side (right of $w$). My new land is at/under sea level on the left of $w$ and at/over sea level on the right of $w$. My land's new profile is modeled by a function $h\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ such that

$h(x)(x-w)\geq 0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$;
$\int_\mathbb{R} h=0$ (this means that no dirt is created nor destructed);
$xh\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$.

One can easily check that $UCM(h)\geq 0$, as one would expect since moving dirt to the right should move the $UCM$ to the right as well.
Moreover, if we assume $h$ to be continuous, then it holds that $UCM(h)=0\iff h\equiv 0$. This means that any slight movement of dirt to the right will be reflected in a movement of the $UCM$. Since the amount of displaced dirt can be seen as (if you want, one half of) $\int_\mathbb{R}|h|$, the above fact motivates the following question:

If $UCM(h)$ is small, can we say the same about $\int_\mathbb{R}|h|$? Or is there a way to move a fixed, positive, minimum amount of dirt from left to right by leaving the $UCM$ arbitrarily small?

The answer to this question is probably yes if you take $h$ to be $1/x$-ish. So I'll add one more constraint to the problem:

$|h|\leq 1$.


I sure am missing something, but however intuitively true the second version of the problem looks to me, I can't find the correct sequence of inequalities that will yield a bound on $\int_\mathbb{R}|h|$ provided $UCM(h)<\delta$.
Can you help me solve this?

Do not delete your question just after getting an answer.  This is disrespectful to the person who took the time to write the answer, and to future readers who might find the Q&A helpful.

Let $w$ be fixed.
Since for any $a\inℝ$ we have that
$$ \int_ℝ |f(x)|dx =\int_ℝ |f(x-a)|  dx$$
and
$$\int_ℝ xf(x)dx=
\int_ℝ (x-a)f(x-a)dx
= \int_ℝ xf(x-a)dx +\int_ℝ-af(x-a)dx=\int_ℝ xf(x-a)dx $$
we can assume that $w=0$.
Next we look for the displacement function $f$ with fixed volume $\text{vol(f)}:=\int_ℝ |f| $ which minimizes $UCM(f)$.
The key property we'll use is that if we move some of the displaced mass closer to $0$, then $UCM$ gets smaller.
To see this, let's say we move a part of $h$, which is wlog left from 0, to the right. Let's call this part $h_l$. More specifically, let $h_l\le 0$ and $ h_l(a)=0$ for all $x\ge a$ for some $a<0$.
Next define $h_r$, the place where we want to take  the dirt from afterwards. We move the position we take the  dirt from closer to the center, so $h_r(x)=0$ for $x<a$, $h_r\le 0$ for $x\in [a,0]$ and $h_r(x)=0$ for $x>0$.
With this we now have that
$$
\int_ℝ x h_r(x)dx\ge \int_ℝ a h_r(x) dx = \int_ℝ ah_l(x)\ge \int_ℝ xh_l(x)
$$
All together we now know that to minimize $UCM$ while keeping $\int_ℝ |f|$ fixed, we want to concentrate the mass of $f$ as close around $0$ as possible.
So the minimizer $f'$ has the shape
$$f':= \text{sign}(x) _{\{-\text{vol}(f)/2,\text{vol}(f)/2\}}(x)$$
So
$$UCM(f)\ge UCM(f') = 2\int_0^{\text{vol}(f)/2} 1 dx = \text{vol}(f)$$

That's how I solved it myself. (Hence the deletion of the question.) But the step where you magically take out the minimizer is far from  trivial,  IMO. The question resembles the following one: take a random variable $X\geq 0$ with pdf $f:[0,+\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$. Suppose $0\leq f\leq 1$. Prove $E[X]\geq \frac 12$.

Do you mean where I deduce the shape? It's not trivial, but still rather straightforward once you know you want as much dirt displacement as possible to be located around 0, since this gives one a strong intuition. As for your example: Yes. Not just expectation, but more generally any moment (not just from probability theory, but from physics) can be bounded by realizing that you minimize it by moving as much of the mass as possible as close to the center as possible. You can even proof that this dirt replacement relocalization is optimal for any measure, not just the Lebesgue measure

Well, how do you formally solve my (second) problem?

The logic of the proof is analogous to the current one, just in a more general framework. I can lay out the assumptions for the general problem I've hinted at earlier if you want. It includes your second one (without needing a pdf), and you can try if you can work it out, and if not ask it as a new question and @me.
